# Remove selection value from duplicate ForeignKey if already selected in the first

Tags: django, django-models

I have the model `Category`:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Category Name", max_length=120, default='', null=True, blank=True)
```

and the model `Organization`

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Organization name", max_length=120, default='')
    m_primary_category = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, blank=True, default='', related_name="+", verbose_name='Primary Category')
    m_secondary_category = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, blank=True, default='', related_name="+", verbose_name='Secondary Category')
```

The user has to add categories first, then in Organization model, when selecting Primary & Secondary fields.

The question is: how to hide/remove category from secondary, if the selection is already selected in primary?

Example: 
- The user add: Cat1, Cat2, and Cat3 in Category Model. 
- The user add: Organization name: Org, select Primary category: Cat1. then the available categories in "Secondary Category" must be: Cat2, Cat3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to show and hide elements without submitting a form you'll need some javascript, using jquery this should be rather easy

```
$('#id_m_primary_category').change(function(){
    // etc
});
```

Of course one cannot trust a user's input so you would still need to validate the form

```
def clean(self):
    if self.cleaned_data.get('m_primary_category') == self.cleaned_data.get('m_secondary_category'):
        raise forms.ValidationError('No')
```